# How can I call a WebMethod to return json with ajax?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json, ajax

I get 404 every time I try this. I can't find the error in my code. I have other webmethod to delete and it works. I am using a WebForm , ADO.NET with a connection string, .NET 4.5.

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static string ListarTiposLicencia()
{
    TipoLicenciaBL objTipoLicencia = new TipoLicenciaBL();
    //Return a DataTable from database with a stored procedure
    DataTable dt = objTipoLicencia.DevolverListaTipoLicencia(String.Empty, String.Empty);
    return DataTableToJSONWithJavaScriptSerializer(dt);
}

public static string DataTableToJSONWithJavaScriptSerializer(DataTable table)
{
    JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    List<Dictionary<string, object>> parentRow = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
    Dictionary<string, object> childRow;
    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        childRow = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
        {
            childRow.Add(col.ColumnName, row[col]);
        }
        parentRow.Add(childRow);
    }
    return jsSerializer.Serialize(parentRow);
}
```

This is the ajax call:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#obtenerLicencias").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "CnfListaTipoLicencias.aspx/ListarTiposLicencia",
            data: '{ }',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                alert(JSON.parse(data));
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert("Error");
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert("error");
            }
        });

    });
});
```

Edit:
I have tried this, but it doesnot work, I get 404 again:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static string ListarTiposLicencia()
    {
        TipoLicenciaBL objTipoLicencia = new TipoLicenciaBL();
        DataTable dt = objTipoLicencia.DevolverListaTipoLicencia(String.Empty, String.Empty);
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt, Formatting.Indented);
        return json;
    }
```

Comment: Build your aspx page to make sure you don't have any error in it.

Comment: remove the data property and see

Comment: I get no compilation errors when I build the project. The method to convert a DataTable to Json needs a DataTable and return a String

Comment: I have tried that (remove data property), but it does not work.

Comment: remove 'data' and 'ContentType' properties. they both are related to data to be sent to server. Since you are sending no data, you don't need them.

Comment: @AksheyBhat It does not work

Comment: Add [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)] infront of the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
//...
DataTable dt = objTipoLicencia.DevolverListaTipoLicencia(String.Empty, String.Empty);
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
Dictionary<string, object> row;

foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
    {
        row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
    }

    rows.Add(row);
}

return serializer.Serialize(rows);
```

But make it sure that the DataTable (dt) populate with some data.

Comment: I added the data and contenType to the ajax call and  this code, and it works, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. Run the following command in the Package Manager Console to INSTALL Newtonsoft:

   Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
2. Put the following Code
   var a = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(parentRow);